# Increasing an integer upon collision with an object. Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have some code which creates and prints the score for my game, but I want the score to increase upon collision with another object.  And despite my best efforts, I cannot seen to figure out how to do it.

This is the code that deals with the score:

```
import SpriteKit

public class Score {
    public let Label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Chalkduster")

    private var currentScore = 0

    public func Setup (fontSize: CGFloat, x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
        Label.fontSize = fontSize
        Label.position.x = x
        Label.position.y = y
        SetScore(currentScore)
    }

    public func SetScore(value: Int) {
        currentScore = value
        Label.text = String(currentScore)
    }

    public func IncrementScore(value: Int) {
        SetScore(currentScore + value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Score class is not inherited with any of the class? BTW it should be and also Label should be added on any node otherwise will not be displayed.

Comment: There's not enough context to troubleshoot. The code here is awkward but OK. Where in your UI code do you extract the SKLabelNode from this class and add it to your scene? Include the whole Scene file.

Comment: The issue is most likely with how you listen for the collision not the Score class. You should show your scene's class.